# Error while installing packages: "triggers ci file contains unknown directive `interest-await'"

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

when I try to install any file it output me this problem :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 242 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive `interest-await'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-0:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of

```
dpkg:
  Installed: 1.18.4ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1.18.4ubuntu1.6
  Version table:
 *** 1.18.4ubuntu1.6 500
        500 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.18.4ubuntu1.2 100 
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 
     1.18.4ubuntu1 500 
        500 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Looks like bug [LP:#1784065](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1784065), which was fixed in 16.04. Hmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like a [Bug #1784065](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1784065) as already indicated by [user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/) in one of their [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168899/error-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-when-installing-fi/1168910#comment1950190_1168899).

From [comment #14](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1784065/comments/14):

> libglib2.0-0 -await trigger requires a newer dpkg than the one in Ubuntu 14.04.

So, since you are on 16.04, you can install an updated version of DPKG using

```
sudo apt install dpkg
```

***On a side note:*** There are **242 packages** that aren't upgraded. Try to upgrade them as soon as possible if you don't want more issues such as dependency issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help.